# Is there a difference between cast and strong type assignment?

Tags: c#, types, compiler-construction

I sort of ran into this today when writing some code. Take the following as an example:

```
long valueCast  = (long)(10 + intVariable);
long valueTyped = 10L + intVariable;
```

Is there any difference between these two or are they compiled to exactly the same thing? Is there a convention for one over the other?

So I know this isn't a critical question (both work). I'm just very curious about what the difference(s) might be!

**EDIT** - Modified the code example to be closer to what my original scenario actually is. I wanted the question to be clear so I replaced the variable with a constant. Didn't realize the compiler would to the arithmetic automatically (thereby changing the answers to this question)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No, they are functionally different, so they certainly won't compile to the same thing.  If the parenthesis were different, and the cast were before the addition, *then* they could potentially compile to the same thing.

Comment: @Servy, point taken. I was about to speak up, but the questioner changing literal `2` into `intVariable` makes my point moot.

Comment: As an FYI for others later. I tried referencing [the type documentation for long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) first. It didn't solve my question but it might help someone else later.

Comment: I discuss your question in my recent article on arithmetic pitfalls, here: http://devproconnections.com/development/c-sharp-code-writing-tips-eric-lippert-math

Comment: Also, this "late promotion" defect is most commonly seen with multiplications, ie, `long p = (long)(a * b * c * d * e);` when what is meant is `long p = (long)a * b * c * d * e);`

Comment: @EricLippert Off topic a bit, but I'm guessing C# uses two's complement to store integer + long numbers then?

Comment: @drew_w: The spec does not come right out and say so, but yes, integers in C# are twos-complement.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, there's a big difference between those two. Not for those particular values, but the exact same expression with different values will show the difference.

In the first version, the addition is done in 32-bit arithmetic, and then the result is converted into a `long`.

In the second version, the first operand is already a `long`, so the second operand is promoted to `long` and the addition is then performed in 64-bit arithmetic.

Of course in this case the compiler will perform the arithmetic itself anyway (and come to the same conclusion in both cases), but it's important to understand the difference between converting the *result* of an operation, and converting one of the *operands* of an operation.

As an example:

```
unchecked
{
    long valueCast  = (long)(2000000000 + 2000000000);
    long valueTyped = 2000000000L + 2000000000;
    Console.WriteLine(valueCast);
    Console.WriteLine(valueTyped);
}
```

Result:

```
-294967296
4000000000
```

Note that this has to be done in an explicitly unchecked context, as otherwise the first addition wouldn't even *compile* - you'd get an error of "CS0220: The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode".

Comment: So (long)10 + 2 and 10L + 2 are equivalents? (I really have the doubt)

Comment: @Areks: Yes, *those* are equivalent... although the latter would allow you to express constants outside the 32-bit range, of course.

Comment: Thank you Jon! I watched your answer being constructed and voted from scratch, I feel like I can die with no regrets now!

Answer (score 7):

Well, this is a compile error:

```
long valueCast = (long)(2147483647 + 2);
```

"The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode."

Whereas this works fine:

```
long valueTyped = (2147483647L + 2);
```

As Jon Skeet says, the difference is whether you convert to `long` before doing the sum, or afterwards.

Comment: And of course, Jon edits in essentially the same example as I'm typing my answer. :)

Comment: @dev_feed Well, it is Jon Skeet we're talking about, after all.

Answer (score 2):

In your example , 10L + 2; equals ((long)10) + 2;

This is not the same as (long) (10+2) because:

(long)(10+2) operation executes as int (32bit) and then gets converted to long (64bit)

((long)10) + 2; operation executes as long (64bit) because 10 gets converted into long before the actual operation